# options menu in android app

Tags: android, menu

I have an app that I want to have a pop up menu for. I have the java and xml for the menu written, however I would like to know if I have to put the java code in the same java activity I want the menu for. The activity is called mainActivity and I want it to have a pop up menu. I wrote the java code for a menu under mainMenu.java with a matching xml layout. My question is can I do it that way and somehow on my mainActivty class import the mainMenu class so they will work together or does all the code need to be only in the mainActivity class? I am wondering because I dont want to have a million lines of code as I add new ideas to my app and would like to use different classes working together.

Comment: post your code what you have tried..

Comment: Popup menu is different and options menu is different. ?What is the exact thing you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add a separate java file for you menu . Just design and XML file for your popup menu and put it into layout folder and in Your main activity you can write code for popup menu.

Please look at the following example. Hope it will help you.

[Example 1](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example)

[Example 2](http://gurushya.com/android-popup-menus/)

Comment: I have exactly what your examples show, a seperate xml file and a java file, however I wanted to know if it was possible to import one java file into another. For example I have my MainActivity class that has several lines of code in it so would it be possible to import a java class with the menu code so that I do not have to continue to put everything into the MainActivity class?

Comment: you can define static method in your util class or other class and can access them in your mainActivity class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MenuTest extends Activity {
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_tab_menu, menu);


   return true;//return true so to menu pop up is opens

}
```

and not forget to press the menu button or icon on Emulator or device